# Taskbar in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

Sorry for my English, but i'm studying it.
My question is this: is possible to create a taskbar like Windows 10 taskbar in vb.net? I'm developing a vb.net OS and i need a taskbar. I would like it to work in such a way as to show an icon for each application (project forms) that are opened by the OS. I've tried using pictureboxes and user controls, but the problem is that I do not know how to add the click event to controls added dynamically to the program.
Thanks to those who will answer, even if you will not be helpful :)

Comment: Look into a FlowLayoutPanel, and use other Panel controls as the frame for a task bar item. Within the individual Panel controls, you can use an image control for an icon and a Label for the text. Research AddHandler for wiring up events on dynamically created controls.

Comment: Sorry to offend you, but no, you are not creating an OS in vb.net. Please clarify your question again! Are you creating a program that works like a a task bar in Windows OS?

Comment: @HardCode do you have a code example? Or a graphic example?

Comment: @HelloXD use Google to explore the controls I've defined, and start working one step at a time. You have to put some effort into it, too.

Comment: Use your favorite search engine and look for AppBar VB.Net.  The Windows taskbar is an example of an AppBar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean you want to make OS using VB.Net, I should tell you that is impossible in VB.Net, If you mean you want to make something emulate the OS as Launcher, You can use this codes to get all opened process and other codes to get that's thumbnails

```
Dim pro() = Process.GetProcesses()
For Each pr As Process In pro
'Your codes goes here
Next
```

Then you can add processes name with that's thumbnail in database and Refresh it using Background Worker, Then Display it in List View Docked at the bottom, that will emulate the Windows 10 Task bar.